# Compiling in VIM across multiple Operating Systems

Tags: linux, windows, macos, vim, terminal

The problem I have is this:

Open up vim on a windows machine, make something that compiles and save it.

Move to a new workstation that is a Mac, open that same file in VIM, makes changes that are correct and get weird results, or sometimes issues with it even compiling.

From what I have found it seems it is because of the encoding the operating systems use with the line returns. Even if the code is good oddities will occur.

After looking around I found this to add to my .vimrc:

```
set fileformats=unix,mac,dos
```

but it does not seem to do the trick. Has anyone else encountered this problem and knows of a efficient solution?

Thank you

Comment: If I'm not making this clear enough or not giving enough information let me know.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you provide a minimal testcase?

Comment: It is probably related to end-of-line encoding. My suggestion would be to install Linux on your Windows machine. Linux is probably much friendler to `vim` users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `'fileformats'` setting should already cover all cases of consistent line endings. You do run into trouble when you have mixed (e.g. LF and some CR-LF) endings, though. You should easily detect those by inspecting the buffer, though. If there are any lines with trailing `^M` characters, you can remove those with

```
:%s/\r$//
```

In any case, such problems indicate a misconfigured tool chain. Configured well, *Revision Control Systems* and file transfer utilities should make line endings transparent. You didn't mention any specifics of your environment, so it's hard to help there.